# EF 5 Unable to verify the compatibility of the model

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm totally new to ASP .Net programming and recently I got this exception when I try to use EF 5 Model First

```
Unable to verify the compatibility of the model because the DbContext instance was not created using Code First patterns. Unable to verify the compatibility of DbContext instances created from an ObjectContext or using an EDMX file.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, my solution Project have 2 projects one for the Data model (EF5) and another for the web application (ASP.NET MVC 4).

If someone issued this error can help me.

Best Regards

Comment: got the same issue and cant figure it out either...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late, I find the answer since one month ago but forgot to edit my post.

The solution (work for me and hope for you guys):

Run the Package manager console (Tools > Library Package Manager I think, my visual studio is in french) and launch these command:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ProjectName <projectName>
Update-Database -Force -Verbose -ProjectName <projectName>
```

And usually it fix the problem

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. To fix it, I had to remove the DB connection string from DataModel project's web.config file and add it in Web Application's web.config file. That's it! :)

When I first created the DataModel project, I was designing the Model Diagrams and generating sql. In the process, I added db connection string to run the generated sql script.

I forgot the remove the connection string DataModel after creating the Web Application that uses the DataModel project.